# angular bootstrap lightbox throws unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-lightbox, angularbootstrap-lightbox

Am newbie to AngularJS and trying to learn stuffs. I am trying to create a gallery with **[`angular-bootstrap-lightbox`](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/blob/master/src/lightbox.html)** and I've included all the necessary dependencies required for the project. Dependencies included are:

```
<link href="css/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Below is my `script.js` file

```
angular.module('home', ["ngRoute", "bootstrapLightbox"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/home', { templateUrl: 'partials/home.html' }).
            when('/about', { templateUrl: 'partials/about.html' }).
            when('/gallery', { templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.html', controller: "galleryController" }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home', templateUrl: 'partials/home.html' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }).controller("homeController", function ($scope, $http, $route) {
        //home controller stuffs
    }).controller('indexController', function ($scope, $location) {
        $scope.isActive = function (route) {
            return route === $location.path();
        }
    }).controller('galleryController', function ($scope, LightBox) {
        $scope.images = [
        {
            'url': 'images/g1.jpg',
            'caption': 'Optional caption',
            'thumbUrl': 'images/g1.jpg' // used only for this example
        },
        {
            'url': 'images/g1.jpg',
            'thumbUrl': 'images/g1.jpg'
        },
        {
            'url': 'images/g1.jpg',
            'thumbUrl': 'images/g1.jpg'
        }
        ];

        $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
            Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
        };
    });
```

But it always throws **unknown provider error** whenever I visit gallery page and this error will be pointing to `Lightbox` parameter mentioned along with `$scope` in `galleryController`. Not sure what is the dependency here. But it does not recognize `LightBox`. I've followed complete steps mentioned there but couldn't quite achieve this right. Any help appreciated.

**Update**

Below is the error am getting.

```
angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LightBoxProvider <- LightBox <- galleryController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=LightBoxProvider%20%3C-%20LightBox%20%3C-%20galleryController
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js:68:12
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js:4418:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js:4571:39)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js:4423:45
    at getService (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js:4571:39)
    at injectionArgs (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js:4595:58)
    at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js:4637:18)
    at $controller (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js:10042:28)
    at A.link (http://localhost:63211/js/angular-route.min.js:18:216)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js:9623:9) <ng-view class="ng-scope">(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13424
http://localhost:63211/gallery Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: could you create a plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: @dreamweiver.. Sorry but not sure how I can replicate this in plunker.. But here is how the **[`design looks`](http://plnkr.co/edit/gq1HwIi2iVUeEAgpoizv?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the dependency injected into `galleryController` from `LightBox` to `Lightbox`. (B is not capitalized in `Lightbox`.) That solves the problem.

Comment: Yes.. Such a silly mistake.. Thanks for solving it buddy.. :)

Comment: Well, i don't have spelling mistake, so... search continues :D